# How correctly create ForeignKey in GORM | Golang application?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

In **PostgreSQL** database I have 2 table:

```
CREATE TABLE WIDGET_TYPE(
    WIDGET_TYPE_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    WIDGET_TYPE_NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE QUESTION(
    QUESTION_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    QUESTION_TEXT TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    WIDGET_TYPE_ID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (WIDGET_TYPE_ID) REFERENCES WIDGET_TYPE (WIDGET_TYPE_ID)
);
```

As you can see each question has only one widget type for offerend answers.

After that step I am trying to design models in Golang application. I use GORM library for this task. I have problem when try to create new entry in `question` table. In the body of the POST request I send JSON object:

```
{
    "question_text": "NEW QUESTION TEXT HERE",
    "widget_type_id": 2
}
```

**ERROR**:

```
pq: insert or update on table "question" violates foreign key constraint "question_widget_type_id_fkey"
```

**models.go**:

```
package models

type WidgetType struct {
    WidgetTypeID   int    `gorm:"primary_key" json:"widget_type_id"`
    WidgetTypeName string `gorm:"not null;unique" json:"widget_type_name"`
}

func (WidgetType) TableName() string {
    return "widget_type"
}

type Question struct {
    QuestionID int `gorm:"primary_key" json:"question_id"`
    QuestionText string `gorm:"not null;unique" json:"question_text"`
    WidgetType WidgetType `gorm:"foreignkey:WidgetTypeID"`
    WidgetTypeID uint
}

func (Question) TableName() string {
    return "question"
}
```

**handlers.go**:

```
var CreateQuestion = func(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    question := models.Question{}
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(request.Body)
    if err := decoder.Decode(&question); err != nil {
        utils.ResponseWithError(responseWriter, http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer request.Body.Close()
    if err := database.DBGORM.Save(&question).Error; err != nil {
        utils.ResponseWithError(responseWriter, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    utils.ResponseWithSuccess(responseWriter, http.StatusCreated, "The new entry successfully created.")
}
```

Where I make mistake?

I add built-in logger support of GORM. In console it show me next SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO "question" ("question_text","widget_type_id") VALUES ('NEW QUESTION TEXT HERE',0) RETURNING "question"."question_id"
```

As you can see `widget_type_id` value 0. WHY?

Comment: Did you create those tables yourself, or is that the SQL generated by GORM?

Comment: The tables are already created before me. I don't generate them by GORM. I found the problem. In struct of `Question` I changed like this `WidgetTypeID int `gorm:"not null" json:"widget_type_id"``. After that it works. But I don't know if it necessary this line: `WidgetType WidgetType `gorm:"foreignkey:WidgetTypeID"``